# Which approach is better, performance wise

Tags: c++, time

Let's say we have a very simple algorithm that check the maximum between 2 numbers:

(1)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int max(int* a, int* b) {
  return (*a > *b ? *a : *b);
}

int main() {
  int a, b;

  cin >> a >> b;
  cout << max(&a, &b) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

(2)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int max(int a, int b) {
  return (a > b ? a : b);
}

int main() {
  int a, b;

  cin >> a >> b;
  cout << max(a, b) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Would be the first case (1) faster than the second case (2) since it does not make a copy of `a` and `b` variables inside the function? I do realise that for this particular example the execution time difference is almost none, but I'll be glad to know if would be a greater difference when it comes to complex functions and data passed.

Comment: Why not run it in a profiler and look at the results?

Comment: Try and measure. My guess would be that they are the same because of compiler optimizations.

Comment: Likely there is *no difference* after the code has been through your compilers optimizer. But, to know for sure; look at the generated asm (of an optimized build). Also; why write your own `max` in the first place when there is [std::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)?

Comment: generally speaking, first case is slower, because it has to deference pointers, note - passing pointer to the function also makes copy of it

Comment: agreed, pointer deference will be slower.

Comment: But what if we pass a more complex variable that has a user-defined data type. Would the derefence be slower in this case?

Comment: `return` is not a function. The extra outer parentheses you have for the return value do nothing.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I saw it in a book and it makes sense to me since in other languages parentheses are also used (e.g. js).

Comment: If you care about performance you should look for algorithmic improvements to your code that may give orders of magnitude speedups, rather than micro optimization like this that will be completely insignificant in the grand scheme of things (your application). Shaving off a few ns here is not going to make a measurable difference - you are just wasting your time while you could be making other, actually relevant, performance improvements.

Comment: you can check https://godbolt.org/z/3jSiV9
and see the pointer version is slower.

Comment: Note that the combination of `using namespace std;` and writing a function named `max` will bite you eventually -- the compiler will complain about a conflict between your `max` and `std::max`. This is why `using namespace std;` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `int` are built in types, if there is no inlining, then using pointers on `int` will be slower than using them directly. `int`s are **cheap** to copy, and don't cost more to store than a pointer, but a pointer will require a dereferentiation before the data can be used.

So in this case, with `max`, the compiler will probably write the same code (try godbolt.org), but for more complex functions, or if the function is in another compilation unit and you are not using link time optimization, you will see a difference in speed. Sometimes.

Of course, if it's more than an `int`, then it will depend. You will have to measure (two pointers are usually fine, that's what `string_view` "are").